# How do I Hook a JPanel into parent/ancestor Container's windowClosing/Closed listener?

Tags: jframe, jpanel, listener, jdialog, jinternalframe

I want to create a 'generic' `JPanel` which can be rendered in any of the higher level `Window` classes (`JFrame`, `JDialog`, or `JInternalFrame` to be somewhat precise.)

I want to be able to 'clean up' some static values when that window is no longer being rendered on screen. Normally, I would do this with a `Window` class (like `JFrame`) and simply `addWindowListener` with proper `windowClosing` or `windowClosed` methods during the creation of the `JFrame`.

Since I desire any of the `Window` classes to be able to render this, I don't even know which kind of listener to add nor do I know which window to add it to.

Is there a way to 'hook' the realization and rendering of the `JPanel` to so that I can add my shutdown hooks no matter what `Window` class renders it?

(I looked at `PropertyChangeListener`, but `componentShown` doesn't trigger on the `JPanel` rendering.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few different options depending on the exact semantics you want. You can register a `ComponentListener` and handle the `componentHidden` method. Another possibility is to register a `HierarchyListener` and check for `DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED` events. You could also use a `HierarchyListener` to find when the panel has been added or removed from a container and add/remove window listeners from the old and new window. The difference between the `ComponentListener` and `HierarchyListener` is that the `ComponentListener` is triggered by any visibility change while the `HierarchyListener`/`DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED` event is triggered when the panel's window is disposed. `ComponentListener` is probably your best bet, but be aware that the panel might be set as visible again in the future.

You can also try the `AncestorListener` `ancestorRemoved` event. It's called if the component itself or any of it's ancestors is made invisibile.

Comment: componentHidden isn't 'thrown' when the enclosing window is closed, I'm guessing since the component/JPanel itself isn't having its visibility property changed. It is simply no longer rendered.    I'll look into the HierarchyListener, though.

Comment: I believe HierarchyListener is the better solution than AncestorListener. Works good. Thanks, Geoff.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally got something working, but I'm not sure I really like the answer.

I added an `AncestorListener` to the `JPanel` at creation. This listener stubbed out the `ancestorRemoved` and `ancestorMoved` events and in the `ancestorAdded` event, would hook the `getTopLevelAncestor()` with the appropriate `WindowListener`/`InternalFrameListener` so that I could run my shutdown code when the window closes.

If there's a better way, I'm open to it. (I'm going to be reviewing the `HierarchyListener` from Geoff.)